# Error de zone.js en Angular 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, angularjs-2.0

Buenas, estimados.

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2015 para programar en C# y Angular 2, al haber hecho unas actualizaciones comenzó a aparecer el siguiente error (Los valores sensibles los cambio por XYZ):

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: 
>   Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
>   Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.):
>   at Function.Zone.assertZonePatched (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:38:23)
>   at new NgZoneImpl (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6219:18)
>   at new NgZone (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6368:30)
>   at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6913:26)
>   at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModuleFactory (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6904:25)
>   at NodePlatform.bootstrapModule (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.js:426:37)
>   at NodePlatform.serializeModule (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\node-platform.js:108:22)
>   at C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:74:63
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
>   at Zone.run (C:\dev\XXX\Utilidades\YYY\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:114:43)

¿Alguno presenta o presentó el mismo error?

Leyendo en internet, encontré que cambiando la línea de declaración de zone.js solucionaba el conflicto, pero lamentablemente no logré solucionarlo de este modo.

Muchas gracias desde ya.

Edit: Adjunto el archivo packages.json, lo cual contiene las dependencias de node.

> {
>     "name": "Angular2Spa",
>     "version": "0.0.0",
>     "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
>       "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
>       "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
>       "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
>       "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
>       "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
>       "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
>       "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
>       "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
>       "css": "^2.2.1",
>       "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
>       "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
>       "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
>       "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
>       "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
>       "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
>       "jquery": "^2.2.1",
>       "preboot": "^4.5.2",
>       "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
>       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
>       "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
>       "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
>       "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
>       "typescript": "^2.0.0",
>       "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
>       "webpack": "^1.12.14",
>       "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
>       "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
>       "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
>       "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
>       "ng2-file-upload": "1.1.4-2"
>     }
>   }

Comment: Por favor, agrega las dependencias node y los imports de main.js

Comment: Estoy utilizando un template en Visual Studio 2015, especificamente el de [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/), por lo que no cuento con un main.js, este se genera automáticamente y al momento de compilar se convierte todo a un único archivo utilizando webpack.

Las dependencias las coloqué en la pregunta original.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Elimina tu carpeta de **node_modules** y vuelve a compilarlo, ya sea con **ng serve** o **npm start** según lo hagas en tu proyecto.

Si tienes otro error, edita tu pregunta con los detalles del error.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Juan y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave gracias.